# Fatal exception error in Android Studio with imported Unity project

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am running into a "Fatal exception error" in Android Studio. I have created an app, that when a button is clicked is supposed to launch a unity project that I have imported into Android Studio in a .aar format. It's throwing a Fatal exception error that I am unsure of how to solve. The app launches fine but when I press the button it crashes. The logcat print out is below:

```
2020-05-05 21:40:56.094 24376-24376/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2020-05-05 21:40:56.131 24376-24406/? I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 4c638fb, I557c585805
    Build Date                       : 10/06/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2020-05-05 21:40:56.131 24376-24406/? I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
2020-05-05 21:40:56.134 24376-24406/? I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2020-05-05 21:40:56.136 24376-24406/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-05-05 21:40:56.137 24376-24406/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-05-05 21:40:56.137 24376-24406/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-05-05 21:40:56.137 24376-24406/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-05-05 21:41:00.711 24376-24376/com.jonathan.vrtest3 W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@da7daa7
2020-05-05 21:41:00.738 24376-24376/com.jonathan.vrtest3 E/onathan.vrtest: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2020-05-05 21:41:00.738 24376-24376/com.jonathan.vrtest3 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-05-05 21:41:00.740 24376-24376/com.jonathan.vrtest3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jonathan.vrtest3, PID: 24376
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jonathan.vrtest3/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:441)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.GetGlViewContentDescription(Unknown Source:20)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<init>(Unknown Source:226)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate(UnityPlayerActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-05-05 21:41:00.742 24376-24376/com.jonathan.vrtest3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jonathan.vrtest3, PID: 24376
    java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
    Unity version     : 2019.3.12f1
    Device model      : OnePlus ONEPLUS A5000
    Device fingerprint: OnePlus/OnePlus5/OnePlus5:9/PKQ1.180716.001/2002242003:user/release-keys

    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jonathan.vrtest3/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:441)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.GetGlViewContentDescription(Unknown Source:20)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<init>(Unknown Source:226)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate(UnityPlayerActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-05-05 21:41:00.748 24376-24422/com.jonathan.vrtest3 D/OSTracker: OS Event: crash
```

And my main_activity.java is:

```
package com.jonathan.vrtest3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final String EXTRA_LOC_ID = "arguments";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //final Intent intent = new Intent(this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);



        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jonathan.vrtest3">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: SOLVED: following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416191/resource-not-found-exception-while-opening-unity-project-in-android-studio) solution, adding `<string name="game_view_content_description">Game view</string>` to my strings.xml file solved the issue. [I used this tutorial](https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-android-app-version-2.751712/)

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest is missing the activity, change it to:

`AndroidManifest.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jonathan.vrtest3">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GameActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and start the unity activity from another activity by chaining the intent with:

`GameActivity.java:`

```
class GamesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your info, I tried it but unfortunately I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Hi! Try this instead and not starting it from the Main activity, silly temp solution at the moment but this seemed to work for me. Haven't had time to deep dive why this issue occurs

Comment: Thanks! would I put the game activity code in the MainActivity.java?

Comment: Separate file in the same folder as the MainActivity. Note the added activity in the manifest

Comment: Sorry for the continued questions, I'm very new to this! Is this correct: `package com.jonathan.vrtest3;`

`import android.app.Activity;`
`import android.os.Bundle;`
``
`import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;`
``
`public class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity(){`

`    @Override`
`    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?){`
`        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`
``
 `       val intent=Intent(this,UnityPlayerActivity::class.java)`
 `      startActivity(intent)`
 `       }`
`}`

Comment: Forgot to change the kotlin code to java, post updated!

Comment: so in your mainactivity do `Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class)` instead. Note that this is just a temp workaround and not a solution

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and a bunch of other tutorials but can't seem to get any further. If you do find a solution please let me know. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually I've got it to work with your solution, when i press the button it launches a white screen, but no unity scene displayed.

Comment: Did you add the intent in the gameactivity?

Comment: hi, yes, exactly as you laid out.

Comment: Have you tried to run the project in ANdroid studio when you exported it from the Unity IDE?

Comment: Hi yes, it works just fine when I run it as an application in AS, its the conversion into a library that is doing my head in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213332/discussion-between-lucho-and-overture).